# Recieving an error when calling an API for reasons unknown

Tags: maven, mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I was trying to call an mule API from Postman client and i recieved a 500 Error. I'm not sure i understand what's going on. I've posted the error below. I'm not sure if this is a maven dependency issue. Any help would be appreciated............................................................................................................

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Error 500</title>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <h1>Status Code: 500</h1>
      Exception: The error below occurred during context initialisation, so no further requests
      can be processed:<br>
      <pre>java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.PropertiesConverter.<clinit>(PropertiesConverter.java:46)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:650)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:445)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:385)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:323)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.<init>(XStream2.java:62)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<clinit>(Hudson.java:3736)
    at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:252)
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:106)
    at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:897)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:73)
    at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
    at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:196)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at Main._main(Main.java:214)
    at Main.main(Main.java:61)
</pre>
      <br>Stacktrace:
      <pre>java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.PropertiesConverter.<clinit>(PropertiesConverter.java:46)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:650)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:445)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:385)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:323)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.<init>(XStream2.java:62)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<clinit>(Hudson.java:3736)
    at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:252)
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:106)
    at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:897)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:73)
    at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
    at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:196)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at Main._main(Main.java:214)
    at Main.main(Main.java:61)
</pre>
      <br>
      <hr size="1" width="90%">
      <i>Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Mon May 02 19:05:42 CDT 2022</i>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is returned by a Jenkins instance. There is nothing generated by Mule in that error. You are either calling the wrong server or the Mule application is just a proxy to Jenkins. Either way the error is in Jenkins and you need to investigate what Jenkins is doing.

Comment: Goodness, i'm an idiot. You were right. I had port 8080 instead of 8081. Thank you again. You've helped me in here more than a few times. I appreciate everything you're doing.